# Where does WooCommerce error message are located in source code (when wrong password is entered)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When a wrong password is entered in WooCommerce based website, it gives an error message like this :

> Error: The password you entered for the email address user@xxx.com is incorrect.

I couldn't figure out where does this error message is written in the Woocommerce source code. I checked the source path here :
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/notices

Also search with "wc_add_notice" in the full source, but that didn't help.
Anyone has idea ?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it comes from WordPress itself and not WooCommerce. Specifically try looking in wp-includes/user.php.

Reference :- https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/user.php#L251